# Adding unicode text to ggvis plot

Tags: r, unicode, ggvis

I am trying to add unicode text to a graphic using layer_text(), but it does not work unless I supply the text as a constant:

```
x = data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c("\\u2799","\\u2794"))

# This one works
x %>% ggvis(~a) %>% layer_text(text := "\\u2794")

# Now does not work
x %>% ggvis(~a) %>% layer_text(text := ~b)

# Nor this way
x = data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c("\u2799","\u2794"))
x %>% ggvis(~a) %>% layer_text(text := ~b)
```

Is there any solution?

Excerpt of my sessionInfo related to locale:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following code (through RStudio) works for me:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
x <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2), b=c("\u2799", "\u2794"))
x %>% ggvis(~a) %>% layer_text(text := ~b)
```

This also works for me:

```
y <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2), b=c("➙", "➔"))
y %>% ggvis(~a) %>% layer_text(text := ~b)
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a relevant excerpt of my `sessionInfo()`

```
# R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# locale:
# [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
# other attached packages:
# [1] ggvis_0.4     dplyr_0.3.0.2
```

So the obvious question is: what is different about your setup?

Comment: It seems it is a locale problem, although I do not understand why (I can print strings with the above characters without any problem).

Comment: what about `plot(c(1, 2), c(1, 1), pch=c("➙", "➔"))`?  If it works in base graphics but not in `ggvis`, then maybe it's a limitation of the windows implementation of `ggvis` (or the [vega](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/) backend)?

Comment: It works! When using with a data.frame one must avoid conversion to factors, but that is simple to solve. I will file a bug. Thanks!